# android custom contacts view

Tags: android, view, contacts

i'm trying to create a custom Contacts view for an app on android.
the following code is something i found on a website while searching the topic.
i'm getting an exception and i don't know why.

this is the contact class:

```
public class Contact {
public Contact(long id, String name, String photo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.photo = photo;
}
public long id;
public String name;
public String photo;
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}
public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
}
```

this is the adapter's code:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Vector<Contact> contactList;
Activity activity;

public ContactsAdapter(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
    fillContacts();
}

public void fillContacts() {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID };
    Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    contactList = new Vector<Contact>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            contactList.add(new Contact(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0])), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1])), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[2]))));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position).id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view==null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.contact, parent);
    }

    TextView contactName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
    ImageView contactPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    contactName.setText(contactList.get(position).name);

    if (contactList.get(position).photo == null){
        contactPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
        contactPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }else{
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactList.get(position).id);
        Uri contactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        contactPhoto.setImageURI(contactPhotoUri);
    }
    return view;
}

}
```

and this is the activity code:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
    ContactsAdapter ca = new ContactsAdapter(this);
    ListView contacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
    contacts.setAdapter(ca);
}
}
```

can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Please post all of you LogCat errors, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: As a note, you should be able to turn `getItem()` into a useful function with `return contactList.get(position);` and changing the return type from `Object` to `Contact`.

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:471)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:497)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at com.ETtech.android.ContactsAdapter.getView(ContactsAdapter.java:62)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1611)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

Comment: 10-18 17:30:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)